# Why it don't fetch DISTINCT category from database

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

I have a table with id and Category columns. I want to fetch only the DISTINCT Category from database but it couldn't do as expected.it gives me output as all categories from table.

I have this block of code:

```
var selectUniqueCategory="SELECT DISTINCT(Category),id FROM images";
var SelectedUniqueCat=db.Query(selectUniqueCategory,category,id);




@foreach(var row in SelectedUniqueCat)
{
                <p><a href="#" data-target="#row_thumbnails">@row.Category </a>
                   <a href="/EditCategory?id=@row.id">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                 </p>
}
```

In for each loop i want to perform two tasks:

1: Get the DISTINCT Category from table

2: Fetch id column and pass each id related with that category to id=@row.id

If i remove id from Query, like:

```
var selectUniqueCategory="SELECT DISTINCT(Category) FROM images";
var SelectedUniqueCat=db.Query(selectUniqueCategory,category);
```

it works fine to get the DISTINCT Category from table but i want to fetch both Category as DISTINCT and id as primary in table.

Comment: Would you like to select all the ids related to the category at once?

Comment: Post some sample input\output data of your table.

Comment: Yes i wana fetch all at once

Answer (score 1):

```
 Hi everyone,
    I have found solution to my problem now i felt it should be share here also.

    as earlier to my question i said i want category and associated id with that simultaneously. following code did work for me.

var SelectQuery="SELECT * FROM images";
                      var selectedData=db.Query(SelectQuery,category,imagePath);

                      var selectUniqueCategory="SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM images ORDER BY Category";
                      var SelectedUniqueCat=db.Query(selectUniqueCategory,category);
```

```html
<a href="/EditCategory?id=@{foreach( var SendId in selectedData )
                                           {
                                               if(row.Category==SendId.Category)
                                               {
                                                   @SendId.id
                                               }
                                           }}" >&nbsp<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></p>
              }
```

It worked for me.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should group by catergory and take the max of max id:

```
SELECT Category,max(id) as idmax , min(id) as idmin FROM images GROUP BY Category
```

Comment: So now the query returns the highest id and the lowest ? Is he asking for that ?

Comment: If i go as as you said i face this error:

System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid column name "id".

at
<a href="/EditCategory?id=@row.id">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></p>

Comment: If you use this query, you have the following fields: idmax & idmin.

Comment: No i dont want anything with min or max.
i want DISTINCT Categories only with id coulmn in that query too

Comment: Show use some sample input and the output you want.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a GROUP BY on the Category column and leave out the DISTINCT, this will only show the id of the first found category.

```
SELECT Category,id FROM images GROUP BY Category
```

Comment: This doesn't work, id should be in the an min/max function

Comment: I face this error if i go with your idea:

In aggregate and grouping expressions, the SELECT clause can contain only aggregates and grouping expressions. [ Select clause = ,id ]

Comment: Which DB do you use MS SQL ?